# PHP CURL not sending/receiving any data - undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Curl has stopped working for me.

I ran some updates on my AWS EC2 server yesterday so I have a feeling that is the cause but I can't figure it out.

I am mainly using Curl to add people to various mailchimp lists. None of these scripts are working now and I am getting browser errors about the connection not being secure:

*"The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified."*

I am also getting the following error in my apache error logs which looks related:

**/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure**

CURL is installed etc (see screenshot) and when I use curl from the command line on my web server the remote server talks back to me... so there is no problem there.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Danny.

```
  // Set API Key and list ID to add a subscriber
  $api_key = 'api key';
  $list_id = 'our list id';
  $dc = 'data center';

  /* ================
   * DESTINATION URL
   * ================
   */

  $url = 'https://' . $dc . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/';

  /* ================
   * DATA SETUP
   * ================
   */

  $pfb_data = array(
    'email_address' => 'some.email@gmail.com',
    'status'        => 'pending',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
      'FNAME'       => 'First Name',
      'LNAME'       => 'Last Name',
    ),
    'interests' => array( 'Interest List ID' => true )
  );

  // Encode the data
  $encoded_pfb_data = json_encode($pfb_data);

  // Setup cURL sequence
  $ch = curl_init();

  /* ================
   * cURL OPTIONS
   * The tricky one here is the _USERPWD - this is how you transfer the API key over
   * _RETURNTRANSFER allows us to get the response into a variable which is nice
   * This example just POSTs, we don't edit/modify - just a simple add to a list
   * _POSTFIELDS does the heavy lifting
   * _SSL_VERIFYPEER should probably be set but I didn't do it here
   * ================
   */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_pfb_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $results = curl_exec($ch); // store response
  $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // get HTTP CODE
  $errors = curl_error($ch); // store errors

  curl_close($ch);

  // Returns info back to jQuery .ajax or just outputs onto the page

  $results = array(
    'results' => $result_info,
    'response' => $response,
    'errors' => $errors
  );

  // Sends data back to the page OR the ajax() in your JS
  echo json_encode($results);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4l5q.png)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the problem was a recently published an update to the NSS package for CentOS 7 systems which was resulting in an Aache error

/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure

The issue was resolved by restarting the Apache and FPM services.

I resolved the problem by restarting my EC2 instance.